# Replacing character in a string after reading from a file java

Tags: java, string, file-io

So I am writing a program that will read in input from a file, replace all the html tags with something like >, for greater than and <, for less than and my logic is correct but for some reason when I try to use the .replace method on the string in the 'from' file it gives me a warning saying that the .replace method is ignored. I tried reading what the ide is telling me but I don't understand what it is saying.

```
public void rewrite(String from, String to) {
    File f = new File(from);
    File t = new File(to);
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(to);
        while (true) {
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                String a = s.next();
                if (a.contains("<") || a.contains(">") || a.contains("&")) {
                    a.replace("<", "&lt;,");
                    a.replace(">","&gt;,");
                    a.replace("&","amp;,");

                }
                fw.append(a);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        fw.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

EDIT:[It is a warning not a compile time error nor a runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcTX5.png)

Comment: How about including the exact error message? Runtime or compile time?

Comment: that looks like it should work, but you may want to try using `String.replaceAll()` instead of `String.replace()`

Comment: Have you tried printing the string 'a' before and after replacing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because of **String immutability**.

You should use

```
a = a.replace("<", "&lt;,");
a = a.replace(">","&gt;,");
a = a.replace("&","amp;,");
```

Otherwise, the replaced String is lost and **the original string is not modified**.